# Write Image To File On Another Server

Tags: java

Currently I have a program on my local host that works great. The program allows users to select images in the view, parses the form data within the servlet, gives all of the images unique id's and adds them into my db, writes the images to a folder on my local host, and then finally displays the images back to the user. I am writing the images to the folder using  `ImageIO.write()`.

However, when I launch this site I would like to hold all static content on another server. Then create a subdomain and point it to that server.

So I am a little confused because all of my business logic will be on the main server (Server A). But when a user uploads an image I want it to be written to the subdomain server (Server B). Is this possible? Can I write an image to a folder off of the business logic server?

Here's a shortened example of how I am doing this now just to give an idea.

```
private static void writeOriginal(BufferedImage original, long imageId) throws IOException
{   
    ImageIO.write(original, "jpg", new File(getOriginalDirectory() +imageId+ ".jpg"));
}
```

...

```
private static String getOriginalDirectory()
{
    return "/Users/Chris/Documents/Instride/Workspace/Instride/WebContent/userImages/original/";
}
```

Comment: I assume you do return the full path in the original code?

Comment: That is the full path. The users folder is as far back as you can go on the mac.

Comment: You should still use Environment Variables to get the user folder, just to be safe

Comment: You can have shared mount or FTP/SCP the file or handle the upload on server B (the latest will involve single sign-on and keeping two applications running).

Comment: How could you FTP the file from server a to b without writing it on server a?